# How does satan whisper to someone born deaf?

Tags: shaitan

People born deaf do not think like we think. They don't hear voices and words as we do when we think to ourselves. They more see "words", or like lips moving.

### How does satan WHISPER to someone that is deaf and born deaf?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are for seeking clarification or constructive criticism, not for argument and debate, answering questions, or discussing site policy.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments,

Satan "whispers" to us (deaf or not) by the means of thoughts. It's in a level that is within us, as referd to "hearts" in the following verse.

> So have they not traveled through the earth and have hearts by which to reason and ears by which to hear? For indeed, it is not eyes that are blinded, but blinded are the hearts which are within the breasts. 22:46

Also thoughts can take many forms.

Comment: The verse has nothing to do with waswas. You might have added surat nas instead: "yowaswiso fi sodori nas"...

Comment: The "heart" I was refering to, is the one that is your "inner-self", whether you are deaf or not.The verse above clearly points it out The verse you pointed out is also good, as its speaks of the " fi soudour al nass" i.e "in the breasts " which is the heart (inner self) that's what I was trying to show.